# How to avoid the nulll values when i load the datas using dataprovider

Tags: php, yii, dataprovider, cgridview

I have one doubt in data provider,

I have more number of fields in the db.If i retrieve the data in specific field,it fetch null values as well as exist values are shown here.I want only the exist values .Without null values i want to load the vales How to do that...Anyone know please help me.

For example C grid view data provider 5 rows have null values in db and another 5 rows have values i want load without null values..please help me.. :(

```
public function actionDataProvider {
    $uid=Yii::app()->user->id;
        if(isset($_GET['user_id']))
            $uid=$_GET['user_id'];
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition=("user_id= $uid ");
            $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('UserGallery',array('criteria'=>$criteria,'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>20)));
        $this->render('product_pic',array('model' => userGallery::model()->findAll($criteria),'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Append to your other `$criteria`'s:

To show NULL values,

```
$criteria->addInCondition( 'columnWithNull', array( null ) );
```

To hide NULL values:

```
$criteria->addNotInCondition( 'columnWithNull', array( null ) );
```

I found this in [Yii documentation (in really reading CDBCriteria source code).](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail)